# Cartesian Product Interval Notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So let’s say $x \in \left[-1, 1\right]$ and $y \in \left[-2, 2\right]$. Is $\left(x, y\right) \in \left[-1, 1\right] \times \left[-2, 2\right]$ the correct way of writing an element being in the Cartesian product?

Comment: as far as I know, yes you are not wrong

Comment: @EvanWilliamChandra Cool, just wanted to make sure. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that’s correct.